# python-pptx: visualise data in two different ways (series1=barchart, series2=line) in same chart

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I am trying to visualise my data in two different ways on the same chart. I want the first series to be a barchart and the second series to be a line chart.

How do I force the second series to display as a line in the code below please? Thanks!

Here's an example dataframe to use:

```
df_chart = pd.DataFrame([['Metric_score', 'Metric', 'Overall', 'Overall', 7.924348, 138, 100.000000, 7.924348], ['Metric_score', 'Taxonomy', 'Q23_Gender', 'taxonomy_Brand1', 8.410000, 2, 1.290323, 7.924348], ['Metric_score', 'Taxonomy', 'Q23_Gender', 'taxonomy_Brand2', 8.000000, 5, 3.225806, 7.924348]], columns=["Metric", "Data type", "Target group", "Target group value", "Mean", "Count", "Percentage", "Overall mean"])
```

The relevant part of my code is this I think:

```
metric = 'Metric_score'
target_group = 'Q23_Gender'

# Instantiate slide
layout = ppt.slide_masters[0].slide_layouts[9]
slide = ppt.slides.add_slide(layout)

# Define chart data 
chart_data = CategoryChartData() # Instantiate chart data object
chart_data.categories = df_chart['Target group value'].astype(str).tolist() # Define chart categories
chart_data.add_series(f"Mean: {metric}", (df_chart['Mean'].values))

# Add Overall mean as second series
df_chart['Overall mean'] = df[(df['Metric'] == metric) & (df['Target group value'] == 'Overall')]['Mean'].values[0]
chart_data.add_series(f"Overall mean: {metric}", (df_chart['Overall mean'].values))

# Add chart to slide
left, top, width, height = Cm(9.5), Cm(3.7), Cm(23.2), Cm(13.5)
chart = slide.shapes.add_chart(
    XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED, left, top, width, height, chart_data
).chart

ppt.save(OUTPUT_FILENAME)
```